# javascript odd and even separation in an array of numbers

Tags: javascript, sorting, console

i wants to separate an array with two groups (odd and even) sequentially. but when i try this:

```js
    var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i]%2 == 0) {
        arr.push(arr.splice(i, 1)[0]);
      }
    }
    
    console.log(arr);
```

```
console.log(arr); 
// [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 6, 2]
```

why 4,8,6,2 instead of 2,4,6,8?

Comment: Short answer: You're getting that result because your for loop is processing 9 times, and since you're moving elements to the end of the array it's processing some of them twice, resulting in what you see

Comment: @Tibrogargan, but not all elements. every element directly after the even element is not checked and stays in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you move **every found** even value to the end of the array:

> ```
> 0: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>      ^-------------v
> 1: 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 2   3 is not checked, because of the incremented index after splicing
>        ^-----------v
> 2: 1 3 5 6 7 8 9 2 4   5 is not checked
>          ^---------v
> 3: 1 3 5 7 8 9 2 4 6   7 is not checked
>            ^-------v
> 4: 1 3 5 7 9 2 4 6 8   9 is not checked
>              ^-----v
> 5: 1 3 5 7 9 4 6 8 2
>                ^---v
> 6: 1 3 5 7 9 4 8 2 6
>                  ^-v
> 7: 1 3 5 7 9 4 8 6 2
>                    |
> 8: 1 3 5 7 9 4 8 6 2
> ```

But, you do not check the value after the found even value, like the value `3` in line zero, because it is never checked and stays at this place, as well as other actually uneven values. You could try the whole again with all even at the beginning of the array, like

```js
var array = [2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
    
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
        array.push(array.splice(i, 1)[0]);
        console.log(i + ': ' + array.join(' '));
    }
}

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

### Solution

You could use a length for checking and reduce the length for every found even value. In this case, the index stays at the value, because at the index is now the next element for checking.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    i = 0,
    l = array.length;

while (i < l) {
    if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
        array.push(array.splice(i, 1)[0]);
        l--;
        continue;
    }
    i++;
}

console.log(array);
```

Or just sort.

By moving odd values to top and then sort by value.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

array.sort((a, b) => b % 2 - a % 2 || a - b);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you do it is so complicated. You can simply achieve that with `array.prototype.filter` and `array.prototype.concat`:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
arr = arr.filter(e => e%2).concat(arr.filter(e => e%2 === 0));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: i wants to do it with a single array.

Comment: The OP wanted both the odd and even numbers in the same array

Answer (score 0):

> why 4,8,6,2 instead of 2,4,6,8?

Basically when half of the iterations are done, it is **re-processing the pushed items**.

You need to change the for-loop as

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length/2; i++) {
  if (arr[i]%2 == 0) {
    arr.push(arr.splice(i, 1)[0]);
  }
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++) {
  if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
    arr.push(arr.splice(i, 1)[0]);
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

**Edit**

And if the order of items is not always sorted, then you apart from sorting it first, you can reduce the `length` variable.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var length = arr.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  console.log(i,arr[i]);
  if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
    arr.push(arr.splice(i, 1)[0]);
    console.log("result ", arr)
    length--;
    i--;
  }
}
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: What if the input is `[1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Comment: @Nemani That isn't the OP's question. He is asking why got this output.

Comment: but actually he wants to separate the even odd, The solution given is wrong for different input

Answer (score 0):

> why 4,8,6,2 instead of 2,4,6,8?

it is because you are modifying the same Array which you are looping through.
to understand better, lets loop through your code

```
after
1st Loop: array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
2nd loop: array: [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2];
3rd loop: array: [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 4];
4th loop: array: [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 2, 4, 6];
5th loop: array: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8];
6th loop: array: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 6, 8, 2];
7th loop: array: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 2, 6];
8th loop: array: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 6, 2];
9th loop: array: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 6, 2];
```

to separate out odd/even in an array, 
we will have to filter out odd and even separately and push `evenArray` in the end of `oddArray`(filtered Array)

```js
var input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

input = input.sort((a, b)=> a-b); //to sort array if not sorted already
var evenArr = [];
input = input.filter(item => {
  if (item % 2 != 0)
    return true
  else {
    evenArr.push(item);
    return false;
  }
})

Array.prototype.push.apply(input, evenArr);

console.log(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be covered by [**lodash**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#partition) `_.partition`:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var [odds, evens] = _.partition(arr, function(n) {
  return n % 2;
});
console.log(_.concat(odds, evens));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Or even shorter:

```
_.groupBy(arr, function(n) {return (n % 2) ? 'odd' : 'even';})
```